# Fechando fora do escopo: eRRRado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, internacionalização

Eu acho que tem algo muito "errrado" nesta imagem.

Also, why is the default comment in English?

[image: Errrado]

Comment: R / errado - *I see what you did there*

Comment: Já tem um [tempo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2139/motivo-de-fechamento-escrito-errado) que esse `r` ta puxado.